# Changing color and transparency of 3DS model

Tags: c#, wpf, helix-3d-toolkit

I want to import a model from a 3DS file and change the color and transparency afterwards. The import works without problems, but how can I change the color and transparency of the model?

My code looks similar to the attached code. My 3DS file is the Ferarri40.3ds from Helix.

```cs
Model3DGroup group = new Model3DGroup();
var hpVp3D = new HelixViewport3D();
ModelVisual3D visual3D = new ModelVisual3D();
var lights = new DefaultLights();
ModelImporter importer = new ModelImporter();
Model3D element;

element = importer.Load(@"Ferarri40.3ds")
group.Children.Add(element);

visual3D.Content = group;

hVp3D.Children.Add(visual3D);
hVp3D.Children.Add(lights);

this.AddChild(hVp3D);
```

I have already tried to change the color with the following code, but without success.

```cs
Material material = new DiffuseMaterial(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black));
importer.DefaultMaterial = material;
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Below i described how do i change material & opacity, without loading file each time. But i need to keep additional object in memory (objects_3d).

here is snippet how to change material during file loading :

```
var mi = new HelixToolkit.Wpf.ModelImporter();
mi.DefaultMaterial = HelixToolkit.Wpf.MaterialHelper.CreateMaterial(Colors.Gray);
helix_model.Content = mi.Load(f_name);
```

here i am loading file into Model3DGroup and later i am changing material

```
            var mi = new HelixToolkit.Wpf.ModelImporter();

            Model3DGroup objects_3d = new System.Windows.Media.Media3D.Model3DGroup();
            Model3DGroup grp_item = mi.Load(fname);
            objects_3d.Children.Add(grp_item);
            //model is imported, now we can change material and opacity:
            ChangeMatrial(objects_3d, default_material, default_opacity);
            helix_model.Content = objects_3d;
            helix_vport.Viewport.UpdateLayout();
```

and here is this simple function to change material afterwards:

```
public void ChangeMatrial(Model3DGroup group, System.Windows.Media.Media3D.Material new_mat, double opacity=1)
            
        {
            foreach (object itm in group.Children)
            {
                if (itm is GeometryModel3D)
                {
                    System.Windows.Media.Media3D.Material new_mat2 = new_mat.Clone();
                    HelixToolkit.Wpf.MaterialHelper.ChangeOpacity(new_mat2, opacity);
                    ((GeometryModel3D)itm).Material = new_mat2;
                    ((GeometryModel3D)itm).BackMaterial = new_mat2;
                   
                }
                else if (itm is Model3DGroup)
                {
                    ChangeMatrial((Model3DGroup)itm, new_mat, opacity);
                }
            }
        }
```